# Auto-Complete adapter size gets reduced to zero

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, autocompletetextview

I have a Main activity which have some tabs each displaying a fragment,among them one is camera fragment in which after capturing an image from camera, a popup appear in which there is an autocompletetextview named lure and a submit button.

The autocompletetextview(lure) adapter is set and its size is printed in dialog popup window, which is same as expected like 15.

The problem is that when i click on the submit button of popup dialog, its size automatically get to 0, and i want the actual size, which is 15.

Here is my code:

```
public class Camera_fragment extends Fragment {
    private AutoCompleteTextView lure;

    private ArrayList<String> lureArrayList
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterLure;
    Dialog layout;
    View view;

    public View onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater inflater, android.view.ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view= inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.camera, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        global=(GlobalData)getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        layout = new Dialog(getActivity());
        getrefrence();
        arrayListDataFetchDB();
        newImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Intent in= new Intent(getActivity(),com.camera.CameraCall.class);
                startActivityForResult(in, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        });
        newImage.performClick();
    }

    private void getrefrence()
    {
        newImage=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.newCapture);
    }

    private void arrayListDataFetchDB()
    {
        lureArrayList=database.select("Select Lure_USED  From LURE Group By Lure_USED Order By COUNT(Lure_USED) DESC");
    }

    private void adapterset()
    {
        adapterLure = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, lureArrayList);
        lure.setAdapter(adapterLure);
    }

    private void initiatePopupWindow()
    {

        //layout.requestWindowFeature(layout.getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        layout.setContentView(R.layout.after_catch_fish_popup_form);
        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int mwidth = display.getWidth();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(layout.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = mwidth;
        layout.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        layout.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        layout.show();
        lure=(AutoCompleteTextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.lure);
        Button submit=(Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.done);
        adapterset();
        lure.setThreshold(1);
        Log.v("adapterSize",""+adapterLure.getCount());
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.v("adapterSize1",""+adapterLure.getCount());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        initiatePopupWindow();

    }

}
```

Comment: I can't see anything immediately wrong with the code you've posted. Are you sure that `database.select(...)` is returning the expected results? Perhaps put in a Log immediately afterwards to check whether it is finding anything.

Comment: Thanks Rubi,But the first Log statement in the popup printing correct size i.e 15 but the Log statement in the submit button click printing 0 size on submit button click.